# Intellisense on wstring displays: npos = 18446744

Tags: c++

In a constructor:

```
CSVBMFBlockModelReader(const wchar_t * const FileNameWithPath, char Delimiter)
{
    _FileNameWithPath = FileNameWithPath;
    _Delimiter = Delimiter;
}
```

Intellisense then reports 
{npos=18446744073709551615 }
and the Immediate Window reports something similiar:

{npos=18446744073709551615 }
    (error): 0
    (error): 0

Am I doing something wrong or is this just intellisense? The code works as expected and _FileNameWithPath.data() returns the correct result. The compiler issues no warning of any kind. The local private declarations are:

```
private:

    std::wstring _FileNameWithPath;
    char _Delimiter;
```

I must state that I am debugging the code after launching it from c#. I am using VS 2015 Enterprise.

Please note I am aware that 0XFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF is the same value. My interest is in why intellisense displays this value to me.

Comment: How are you launching it from C#?

Comment: What is `npos`?

Comment: @Tanveer Badar [DllImport(DLLName, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall,
                   CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, EntryPoint = "ReadVulcanCSVFileHeader")]
 public static extern void ReadVulcanCSVFileHeader([In] string FileNameWithPath, ref uint FieldCount, 
                                                          FeedBack FeedBack, ref int ErrorCode);

Comment: 18446744073709551615 is 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF which is -1 interpreted as an unsigned integer. It sounds like a type mismatch or uninitialized value. However, the code you're showing seems to have nothing to do with the error you're reporting so this question is not exactly answerable.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I am hoping that someone may be able to confirm that they have also had the same experience and have concluded this is not a problem.

Comment: @Code Gray No, I am not asking why 0XFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF is the value that it is. I am asking why intellisense does not display something useful instead of what it did display. In particular is this an indication of an error of some kind?

Comment: FYI: You got my name wrong, so the ping didn't actually work. I just happened to have this tab still open where I could see your reply. Anyway, I don't understand where your confusion persists. Intellisense is displaying this long integer value because it's equivalent to -1 as an unsigned integer. You say you already know that. The `npos` field is -1 because that's the default value for that field. It's only an error if you had just previously called a member function that performs a search or otherwise looks for a position; in that case, it would indicate no valid position was found.

Answer (score 1):

You're just seeing a part of `std::string`/`std::wstring`.  `std::string::npos` is a sentinel value and is used to indicate when a member function doesn't find a valid position in the string.  It is defined as

```
size_type npos = -1;
```

and since `size_type` is a unsigned integer type it wraps around to be the largest number that type can hold.  In this case you are seeing the maximum value a 64 bit unsigned integer can hold.

Comment: Thanks, but is this any reason for concern?

Comment: @Peter It shouldn't be.  It's just intellisense being senseless.